# How do I use text file inputs in a cmd prompt batch

Tags: syntax, cmd

What I am trying to do is to run the installation of TightVNC on 130+ different computers

I currently have it set up as:

```
echo INSTALLING TightVNC AND CONFIGURING



msiexec /i "\\10.X.X.X\data\hardwareAssets\TightVNC\tightvnc-2.7.10-setup-32bit.msi" /quiet /norestart 
ADDLOCAL="Server,Viewer" 
VIEWER_ASSOCIATE_VNC_EXTENSION=1 
SERVER_REGISTER_AS_SERVICE=1 
SERVER_ADD_FIREWALL_EXCEPTION=1 
VIEWER_ADD_FIREWALL_EXCEPTION=1 
SERVER_ALLOW_SAS=1 

SET_USEVNCAUTHENTICATION=1
VALUE_OF_USEVNCAUTHENTICATION=1
SET_PASSWORD=1
VALUE_OF_PASSWORD=Test
```

Using PSexec I am trying to have it run X amount of times from a list of IP addresses from a text file to shorten the time this takes.

```
psexec \\@test.txt
```

However it is failing at the above step. I am certain that I simply have the incorrect syntax but after searching for over 2 hours I cannot find the the correct way to call for the text file.
We can run it on individual computers but as this project has 9-15 phases I would like to shorten the time of completion.

Answer (score 0):

Found example at http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-file_topic6519.html

```
psexec @test.txt -u adminuser -p password
```

The executed installation will have to be accessible via network, as parameter to psexec will be executed locally